# Windows Update falsely claims that the exclude drivers policy is set

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, group-policy

### Update: issue appears fixed, raises more questions than it answers

Goodness gracious, so I just tried to simply enable the policy and then disabling it again (the good old turning it off and on again), and of course it's fixed now... Still doesn't make sense though because of the complete reset of all policies to factory defaults before, that didn't help (I rebooted several times in the mean time as well). Windows has mysterious ways I guess.

Although this doesn't comfort me at all. Why did Windows Update see the wrong/phantom policy setting before? Are (group) policy settings even reliable? Is *Windows* reliable for that matter...

---

Windows Update is claiming that the policy to exclude driver updates has been set, which the screen shot below proves is not the case:

[image: Windows Policies]

What could be the cause of this?

---

#### Windows specifications & Environment

```
Edition:    Windows 10 Pro  
Version:    1809  
OS build:   17763.437
```

The computer is running in a home environment (standalone).

#### What I've tried so far

- Reset all group policies to factory defaults:

```
RD /S /Q "%windir%\System32\GroupPolicyUsers"
RD /S /Q "%windir%\System32\GroupPolicy"
gpupdate /force
```

- Checked the state of the `ExcludeWUDrivers` registry entry (located at `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\WindowsUpdate\UpdatePolicy\PolicyState`): `0`

Comment: Good question!
I suggest that you remove your self-answer (the first two paragraphs) from your question and put them in an answer of your own instead. (Did you know that Super User allows you to answer your own question?)

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue.  I was able to get the problem to go away by enabling the "Do not include drivers with Windows Update" policy, and then setting it back to "Not Configured".

Comment: The author’s screenshot clearly indicates this policy is already set to that value.

Comment: @Ramhound it is necessary to toggle it explicitly, then all will work ok

Comment: @vladon - If one has to toggle this policy then there is something else going on.  I suspect the author of this answer simply didn't understand the author of the question had already configured the policy.

Answer (score 3):

Do this for all policies in the `Administrative Templates\Windows Components\Windows Update` group: First change to `Enabled` (or `Disabled`) then click Apply, then restore again to `Not Configured` and click Apply again. When you "fix" the correct policy, the annoying notice will disappear instantly if you focus "Settings\Update", so no need to restart and you can check after each change (saves you extra clicking).

[image]

Also do the same with `Allow Telemetry` in `Administrative Templates\Windows Components\Data Collection and Preview Builds` - make sure it is not `Disabled`.

[image]

Comment: It worked fine for 21H2 (build 19044). Thanks! The only 'problem' for me was that the message _Some settings are managed by your organization_ did not disappear until I clicked _Home_ and then _Update & Security_, so unfortunately I cannot tell _which_ of the settings that caused this annoying behavior. Maybe someone else will be able to tell ...

Comment: I think any of the settings could be buggy

Answer (score 1):

you should check this entry too :
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\WindowsUpdate\UX\Settings\ExcludeWUDriversInQualityUpdate

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.

Comment: I tried this one. A similar approach worked fine for 1803 (build
17134), but sadly it doesn't work for 21H2 (build 19044).
~ * ~
However, in my registry, the `UX` entry of
`HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\WindowsUpdate`
does not even exist.
I created an entry
`HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate\ExcludeWUDriversInQualityUpdate`,
as described
[here](https://pureinfotech.com/exclude-driver-updates-windows-10/#block_driver_updates_windows10_regedit).
I then set it to 0 (zero).

Answer (score 0):

Probably something in the registry still. These are all the places to look, thanks to [Ten Forums](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/48277-enable-disable-driver-updates-windows-update-windows-10-a.html):

- [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\PolicyManager\current\device\Update]
  "ExcludeWUDriversInQualityUpdate"=dword:00000000
- [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\PolicyManager\default\Update]
  "ExcludeWUDriversInQualityUpdate"=dword:00000000
- [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\PolicyManager\default\Update\ExcludeWUDriversInQualityUpdate]
  "value"=dword:00000000
- [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\WindowsUpdate\UX\Settings]
  "ExcludeWUDriversInQualityUpdate"=dword:00000000
- [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate]
  "ExcludeWUDriversInQualityUpdate"=dword:00000000

Answer (score 0):

Go to: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate` and delete the `ExcludeWUDriversInQualityUpdate` entry.

Found here: [Tenforums: Some settings are managed by your organization](https://www.tenforums.com/general-support/110752-some-settings-managed-your-organization.html)