# Windows 10 Security Tab missing from file properties

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, group-policy

I have a Windows 10 laptop  and all the files in the Downloads directory are missing the Security tab from the file properties view.

Folders in Downloads do have the Security tab.

Files do not.

In the local group policy editor, Local Computer Policy | User Configuration | Administrative Templates | Windows Components | File Explorer | Remove Security Tab is set to 'not configured'.

What else could be causing this?  There are a ton of links on Google and questions here which say the group policy setting I just mentioned fixes it.  But I still cannot access the security settings on my files in the Downloads folder.

Thanks!

Comment: I had this problem with a file on a USB drive, but when moving it to my desktop the tab appeared. Not that it should matter, but is the Downloads directory aliased to a remote device?

Comment: @dcwaters I had the same issue with a file on the WSL mount, so I guess this security tab is not applicable on mounted resources.

Answer (score 4):

You may try the following steps to show the security tab on Windows 10:

1. Type regedit in RUN dialog box and press Enter. It'll open Registry Editor. 
   Now go to following key:
2. HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer
3. In right-side pane, create a new DWORD NoSecurityTab and set its value to 0. It'll immediately add "Security" tab for all files and folders properties window. If it doesn't add the tab, you can log off, restart your system and check.

Comment: The author indicated that the group policy in question is configured as "not configured", "not configured", is treated as the policy being disabled.

Comment: Thanks @Ramhound... I've tried it both a "disabled" and "not configured" for the pedantic in here.  Even though, as you mention, disabled and not configured have the same effect.

Comment: @laurayuan please check out my original post again.  This works for folders but not for files.  I'm asking what is the solution for files.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For any disobedient entry in the Group Policy Editor that you want to
set to *Not configured*, try :
<sup>1</sup>

*Enabled > Apply > Disabled > Apply > Not configured > Apply*

---

Setting an entry in the Group Policy Editor doesn't always "bite".
This is a *known bug*, reported in
[this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1620698) and in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1745956).

### References

- [How to deal with buggy group policies](https://superuser.com/a/1620698)
- [How to work around a bug in the Local Group Policy Editor](https://superuser.com/a/1745956)

---

<sup>1</sup>
My answer is a bit tentative, so I don't know if it will solve
your problem.
Others report that just one of *Enabled > Apply* **or**
*Disabled > Apply* should suffice before
doing *Not configured > Apply*.

Comment: While valuable to see it's a known bug, unfortunately it did not work in my case