# My PC can't write to any USB external storage device but can write to my Phone storage

Tags: windows, windows-10, usb-storage

I recently noticed that I couldn't write files (or delete files) to any external usb storage using my PC.
Here is what happens when I try to create a new folder.

[image: Creating new folder 1st window popup]

[image: Creating new folder 2nd window popup]

I can't get past the 2nd window popup. It just repeats.

I also can't format the usb drive. Once I click the "Format..." in the right-click context menu, it gives me this message:

[image: Format drive popup]

I hope someone can help me find what's causing this and how to fix it so that my pc could write to external USB storage devices.

Here is a list of notable things:

- Flash drive is brand new. I can copy files to it using my sister's laptop and PC. I can't on my PC.
- The file system doesn't matter. Can't write to NTFS or FAT32.
- Can't write to flash drive or external HDD
- My PC has no malware/virus
- Tried booting in Safe Mode. Still couldn't write.
- Can copy files from flash drive into my internal SSD/HDD. Basically I can still read the files.
- What's weird is I can write files to my Phone Storage. Windows treats it differently for some reason. [image: Phone Storage screenshot]
- I can copy files from another computer to my internal drives through LAN and vice versa.
- The OS is Windows 10 pro. Windows is updated. No other updates in the queue.
- I am using a Local Account. It has Administrator privileges. I even created a new local user with admin privileges and it can't write to the storage either.
- Tried creating a text file using CMD with elevated privilege. It gave an "Access is denied" message. [image: CMD message]
- This is my own PC. It is not a company/corporate owned PC.

I have tried everything I could find on the internet (except for re-installing Windows) and nothing works. I would like to save the re-installing of windows as a last resort.

Here is a list of fixes I have already tried and didn't work:

- Checked registry values for WriteProtect. It didn't exist at first. I added it and set it to 0.
- Defective device. Bought a new one. It turns out even the old one works on my sister's laptop/PC.
- Add full control permissions in Security tab. By default, it already had the "Authenticated Users" group. I still added the "Everyone" group afterwards. (This is for NTFS only)
- Uninstalled USB controllers in Device Manager and restarted the PC.
- Used diskpart to try to remove read-only attribute. [USB drive wasn't even read only to begin with](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HVoub.png)
- Tried different USB ports. Couldn't write using any.
- Checked Local Group Policies if the "Deny write access" in the Removable Storage Access settings is set to Enable. It wasn't.
- Used DISM/sfc. It ran successfully for both. It didn't fix the problem.
- Download latest drivers from Asus (x570 motherboard) and reinstall.
- Did an In-place Upgrade of Windows

I'm really hoping someone will be able to help me with this.

Comment: I don't know your answer but might be able to provide some clues.  Your phone storage is not a file system from Windows' point of view.  It uses a completely different mechanism.  Adding the type of windows you are using (home/pro) and if it is on a domain or not will help people help you.  This sounds like a group policy setting to me.

Comment: I don't know the answer.. but seeing as it only takes an hour or two to get there i'd just go ahead and re-install windows.

Comment: Check if in the registry you have a key named `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\StorageDevicePolicies`.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas I forgot to mention that I already tried looking into the group policy settings and there isn't anything there. Everything is in a not configured state. The phone storage working is definitely something that I took notice on when it worked. Although I couldn't find anything about how Windows separates it from flash drives.  Thank you so much for the comment. I'll definitely go down this route of looking for the difference with the phone storage.

Comment: @Mastaxx I really don't want to go through reinstalling every app I have. Also, I don't really have a need for writing to USB storage, at least for now. I'm just stumped on why it's happening and just want to know the answer.

Comment: @harrymc I already looked into that. At first, that key didn't exist, so by default, the WriteProtect should be considered as 0. But since I wanted to make sure, I still created it when I couldn't find it and added the WriteProtect DWORD and put the value as 0. It didn't work unfortunately.

Comment: Phone storage is  MTP, which isn't the same as what a regular USB drive users. You don't need to reinstall, but the usual sfc scannow and using DISM to check/fix your install might be a good idea

Comment: @JourneymanGeek I'll try those out. Thank you for the tip!

Comment: This is a very well-written and researched question!

Comment: Is this a corporate PC? Group Policies are a thing of the past. Azure AD with Mobile Device Management is where it's at nowadays.

Comment: @DanielB This is my own PC.

Comment: Well if you say so. One possible cause is the BitLocker policy (remember, MDM). It can require drives be encrypted, otherwise they are read-only.

Comment: Have you tried re-installing the drivers for the USB controller / BUS? What manufacturer and model is it.. I would recommend downloading the latest drivers from your manufacturers website rather than allowing the drivers to be re-installed through microsoft windows update.

Comment: @Mastaxx I have tried that already. Downloaded the drivers from Asus. Unfortunately, it didn't fix the problem.

Comment: Do you have any restore point on Windows 10 to fall back on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally found the fix for this issue! I should have done this the first time I was looking into it but it makes sense why I didn't.

---

It was a local group policy all along. Specifically this setting, Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > System > Removable Storage Devices > Removable Disks: Deny write access.

Usually, if this is the cause, it should be in an "Enabled" State. The fix for that is to set it from "Enabled" to "Disabled" or "Not Configured" and you should be able to write to external drives. But its State on my PC was set as Not configured, so I immediately wrote it off as the possible cause of the issue.
[image: Local Group Policy]

After doing almost everything except for reinstalling Windows, I tried to look back on the fixes that I went through and noticed that I technically didn't do the steps for this fix. So I went for it. I set it to "Enabled". Applied the change. And then set it back to "Not configured" and applied the change again. Lo and behold, it worked! I can write to any USB drive.

---

Maybe the true setting just wasn't being displayed in the Local Group Policy Editor. I don't really know what caused the issue, I'm just glad that it is fixed now. I can finally rest. Thanks to everyone who helped out!

The lesson I learned is always try to turn it on and off again or vice versa. XD

Comment: Nice catch. Policy Editor can be tricky with unconfigured. If the value was once upon a time set to either enabled or disabled and then set back to unconfigured in some cases the previous policy value remains in effect and it won't return to the default value. This only happens on some GPO fields. Most will return to default. It seems this is one of the fields that don't. Lesson learned: If it has a policy and when in doubt set the policy explicitly and don't rely on the "unconfigured" default value.

Comment: This is a *known bug* in the Group  Policy Editor.
It has been reported in
[this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1620698).
~ * ~
I also suspect that the same bug is at play in
[this question](https://superuser.com/q/1522576),
but it hasn't been resolved, so I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Mmmh... Couple of things here...

The phone uses MTP (Media Transfer Protocol) which uses different drivers than the USB "Mass Storage Device Protocol" which is typically used by USB memory sticks and USB connected HDD/SDD drives.  Both run on-top-of the basis USB system.

Since MTP works there is nothing wrong with your USB controller/drivers/ports. The problem has to be in either the drive itself or the USB Mass Storage Drivers.

1. USB Mass Storage is on business/school supplied computers (or BYOD devices under "device managemnt" from an organization) often blocked by group-policy or device-management policy.
   If that is the case you will have to talk to your system admin. You won't be able to easily circumvent that (and you may be in trouble if you try to mess with it).
2. It is possible the USB device itself thinks there is a problem when it is connected to your PC and it will refuse to talk to your computer to prevent further "damage". This sometimes happens if a power-hungry USB device doesn't get enough power from the PC or there is some subtle compatibility issue between the USB device and the USB controller chip in your PC. It is very rare though. *And since another USB device showed the same issue it is not likely in your case.*
3. Something is wrong with the USB Mass Storage Drivers on your computer. This is I think most likely the problem. As Journeyman Geek already mentioned in the comments the usual SFC /SCANNOW and DISM repair commands (I'm typing on my phone now. Bit complicated to find the correct syntax for those, but you can easily Google them.) will probably fix that.
   If SFC/DISM doesn't help doing an upgrade installation of Windows (same version or newer than you have now) on top of your existing installation should fix that while keeping all you files/settings. (I still recommend making a backup before you try that though!!! Just in case...)

Comment: I remember one of my friend's systems had this issue. I couldn't talk her through the 'proper' steps for option 3 (or they didn't work) and I ended up talking her through a reinstall which fixed it.

Comment: _"The problem has to be in either the drive itself or the USB Mass Storage Drivers"_ - or simply OS policies.

Comment: @gronostaj I still consider that "drivers" and I covered that in point 1

Comment: There are no group policies implemented on my PC. And doing an upgrade installation of Windows did not fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You have done almost everything conceivable for solving the problem.

The problem is probably in Windows, not in hardware, so I suggest doing
these checks (in order of gravity):

- Check for drivers on the manufacturer's website that might be
  connected: USB controller, chipset and motherboard.
  Check also for a BIOS update (update carefully and don't force it).
- Run `chkdsk`
- Test disk SMART status by software such as
  [Speccy](https://www.ccleaner.com/speccy)
- Testing Windows integrity by:

  - [Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/7808-use-dism-repair-windows-10-image.html)
  - [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html)
- [Repair Install with an In-place Upgrade](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html).
  This is the same as doing a major Windows update, so mind your backups.
- Reinstall Windows from scratch
- If nothing helps : Send the computer to a repair-shop for the
  USB controller to be checked.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. After work, I'll go through these one by one except maybe for the last two.

Comment: I tried everything except the last three. I was hoping DISM and sfc would fix the problem but it didn't. I'm contemplating right now if I should do a "Repair Install".

Comment: Repair Install is not more dangerous than Windows Update, but just the same, taking backups is important. Ensure to download the latest Windows version, so as not to downgrade to a previous version.

Comment: I can't believe it. Doing an In-place Upgrade didn't fix the issue. I might just have to consider reinstalling windows.

Comment: And if this doesn't work, then all that is left for the problem is hardware. If this is onerous, take an image backup of the whole disk, so you can return it relatively easily if the reinstall didn't help, or if the repair-shop destroys Windows. Don't use Windows Backup, but a utility such as AOMEI Backupper Freeware.